# Unit testing with PowerMock, precision problem when comparing seconds

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermock, powermockito

I'm trying to unit test a time function using powermock, but I'm sometimes having trouble getting through the assertEquals() when comparing the current time with system clock. The expected time is 2 seconds off. Here is my code for reference:

```
@RunWith(PowerMock Runner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Calendar.class, time.class})
public class TEST {

    @Test
    public void testTime() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Calendar.class);
        Mockito.when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(calendarInstance);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DD_DOT_MM_DOT_YYY);
        assertEquals(sdf.format(calendarInstance.getTime()), time.getDate(DD_DOT_MM_DOT_YYYY)); }
    }
    
//inside the time.getDate function
    
public static String getDate(String format) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

And here's the Junit output I sometimes get which indicates the failure:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure:
Expected :20:43:18
Actual :20:43:20
```

I have tried a few ways to get around this, but I couldn't get it working reliably. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The code sample does not show how `time` object in `time.getDate` being initialised.

For this test - you should initialise both the `time` and `Calendar.getInstance()` with same seed value else the result is unpredictable.